# center container to middle of page

Tags: html, css

I have this, html and css

```html
<div class="Mycontainer">

  <div class="avatar">
    <img alt="" aria-hidden src="https://cdn.svgporn.com/logos/apple-app-store.svg" class="background" />
    <img alt="Avatar" src="https://cdn.svgporn.com/logos/apple-app-store.svg" width="100" height="100" />
  </div>

  <div class="avatar">
    <img alt="" aria-hidden src="https://cdn.svgporn.com/logos/airbnb.svg" class="background" />
    <img alt="Avatar" src="https://cdn.svgporn.com/logos/airbnb.svg" width="100" height="100" />
  </div>

  <div class="avatar">
    <img alt="" aria-hidden src="https://cdn.svgporn.com/logos/figma.svg" class="background" />
    <img alt="Avatar" src="https://cdn.svgporn.com/logos/figma.svg" width="100" height="100" />
  </div>

  <div class="avatar">
    <img alt="" aria-hidden src="https://cdn.svgporn.com/logos/atom-icon.svg" class="background" />
    <img alt="Avatar" src="https://cdn.svgporn.com/logos/atom-icon.svg" width="100" height="100" />
  </div>

  <div class="avatar">
    <img alt="" aria-hidden src="https://cdn.svgporn.com/logos/gitlab.svg" class="background" />
    <img alt="Avatar" src="https://cdn.svgporn.com/logos/gitlab.svg" width="100" height="100" />
  </div>

  <div class="avatar">
    <img alt="" aria-hidden src="https://cdn.svgporn.com/logos/google-cloud.svg" class="background" />
    <img alt="Avatar" src="https://cdn.svgporn.com/logos/google-cloud.svg" width="100" height="100" />
  </div>
  

</div>

<style>
.avatar {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;

  border-radius: 10%;
  overflow: hidden;

  /* Subtle inner border */
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.015);
}

.avatar img {
  height: 70%;
  width: 70%;
  z-index: 2;

  /* Optionally add a drop shadow to the main image  */
  /* to make it feel "lifted"    */
  filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12));
}

.avatar .background {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  transform: scale(2);
  filter: blur(13px) opacity(0.2);
}

/* Irrelevant styling */

.Mycontainer {
  width: 200px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  place-items: center;
}

</style>
```

it doesn't go to the center of the page, it only goes to the top left. how can I fix this with css? I set the width of `Mycontainer` to 200px width, which i think is the problem, but i cannot have it any bigger, as i need it to be centered to my page, but with a specific set width. Is this possible?

Answer (score -1):

add to the Mycontainer's class the following:

```
height:100vh;
```